# How to get constant name by filename

Tags: ruby

Given a filename, I would like to know if there is a ruby way to obtain the constant name for it.

e.g:

`"lib/myproject/connect.rb"` => `MyProject::Connect`

p.s: I know I can create a script for this.

EDIT: consider only the first one at the top.

Comment: What if that file contains several constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wanna take a look at the implementation of `Inflector#camelize` in `ActiveSupport`, see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize